# ImportError: cannot import name 'GPTSimpleVectorIndex' from 'llama_index'

Tags: python, langchain, llama-index

I am getting an `ImportError` while using `GPTSimpleVectorIndex` from the `llama-index` library. Have installed the latest version of llama-index library and trying to run it on python 3.9.

```
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, ServiceContext
ImportError: cannot import name 'GPTSimpleVectorIndex' from 'llama_index' (E:\Experiments\OpenAI\data anaysis\llama-index-main\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\__init__.py
```

The source code is given below,

```
import os, streamlit as st

from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, ServiceContext
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try use ‘GPTVectorStoreIndex’ instead of ‘GPTSimpleVectorIndex’:

```
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex, ..
```

Answer (score 4):

As per llama_index 0.8.40, `GPTSimpleVectorIndex` is deprecated and replaced by `VectorStoreIndex`.

To do a query, you need to change from `index.query` to

```
query_enginge = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("My query")
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it describes how to query the `VectorStroreIndex`. Note there is a typo in the example: it should be `query_engine`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [issue](https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/issues/1900#issuecomment-1532432267), `GPTSimpleVectorIndex` was renamed to `GPTVectorStoreIndex`, try removing it from the end of your imports. So you can simply import it as mentioned by [RadoTheProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17523352/radotheprogrammer) above.

**Before**

```py
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex
```

**After**

```py
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced GPTSimpleVectorIndex , GPTVectorStoreIndex

```
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('../news').load_data()
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
r = query_engine.query("how did the pandemic effect business")
print(r)
```

the version of llama_index used was llama-index==0.9.4

Answer (score -3):

you should change GPTSimpleVectorIndex to GPTVectorStoreIndex. this work for me.

Comment: Don't the existing answers already cover this? Please don't repeat answers.